# Can we customize search in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using yii2 gridview application, which gives search option by default. griview search gives results if entries "contains" given values.That is if we type "ab" in search box then it will give results which contains "ab".

```
<?php 
          $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'alias', $this->alias])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'company_mail', $this->company_mail])
        ?>
```

what I want is to search for starting with "ab" ?
how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gridview display data for dataProvider
as  you can see  in a tipical  gridview related  action like actionIndex

you can see that the dataProvider is build usig a search model as a new class  for YourmodelSearc()  with method search()

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

and a search function tipically contail the find() and AndFliter() function for build dinamically the query for dataProvider

```
public function search($params)
  {
      $query = YourModel::find();

      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
      ]);

      if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
          return $dataProvider;
      }

      $query->andFilterWhere([
          'your_numeric_col1' => $this->your_col1,
          'your_numeric_col2' => $this->your_col2,
          ......
          'id' => $this->id,
      ]);

      $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_string_colx', $this->your_string_colx])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_string_coly', $this->your_string_coly])
         .......
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_string_coln', $this->your_string_coln]);

      return $dataProvider;
  }
```

So extending, redefining or manipulating   the search()  or build a new customSeach() 
you apply multiple filter  or chainging the default behavior for query filter

for the `like` operator when the yii2 filtering default is not what you need  you could try using the andWhere in  string format.

do the fact that andFilterWhere don'k allow the use of literal conditition you can add  a simple andWhere testing for null value 
the bottom of the query building code

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_string_colx', $this->your_string_colx])

     .......
      ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_string_coln', $this->your_string_coln]);

if (isset($this->your_string_coly)){
    $query->andWhere('your_string_coly like concat("%", :param1)',
        [':param1'=> $this->your_string_coly])

}

return $query;
```

Comment: what should I do to make search  on the basis of starting letter? means If I enter "ab" in search textbox It shouls give entries starting with "ab"

Comment: for  a string that start  with "ab"   (alias  in mysql  like 'ab%' )  the normal behavior of andFilterWhere should be enough  -- instead if you want a match for binary 'ab'  could be you need  =  and not like

Comment: actually it is taking the alphabates "%ab%" not "ab%". and i Just want it to give result for the string that starts with alphabates in search textbox

Comment: sorry for ask u again, but am new to yii2... getting this error .....Argument 1 passed to yii\db\Query::andFilterWhere() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app\backend\models\CompaniesSearch.php on line 103 and defined..... Iused the query ......$query->andFilterWhere('name like concat("%", :param1)',[':param1'=> $this->name])

Comment: what  mean not .. working ?  ... you have errro?   ... you have not expected  result  ?   ...

Comment: not showing error.. but I enter value in search text box.. it gives "no result found"

Comment: check if  the code is correctly  used and the condition work properly

Comment: It works but It was giving string ending with letters. ..I changed it like this... if (isset($this->name)){
    $query->andWhere('name like concat(:param1,"%")',
        [':param1'=> $this->name]);

Comment: @Goli   thank you for the rigth editing of the answer   .. upvoted